# Как покрасивее написать обработку ошибок в Rust?

Tags: rust

Есть примерно вот такой кусок кода парсера сайта с использованием [select](https://github.com/utkarshkukreti/select.rs):

```
extern crate select;

use select::document::Document;
use select::predicate::{Class, Name, And};

fn main() {
    // Пример; реальность чуть сложнее, но не суть
    let html = "<main>
        <div class='vote-topic'>
            <div class='vote-item vote-count'>
                <span id='vote_total_blog_123'>+15.00</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>";

    let page = Document::from(html);

    let blog_id: u32 = page.find(And(Name("div"),Class("vote-item")))
        .find(Name("span")).first()
        .unwrap().attr("id")
        .unwrap().split('_').collect::<Vec<_>>().last()
        .unwrap().parse::<u32>().unwrap();

    println!("Blog id: {}", blog_id);
}
```

Я попытался его переписать так, чтобы на выходе получить Option (который потом переведу в Result; конкретно здесь сохранение точной причины ошибки не интересует). Результат работает, но выглядит, мягко говоря, не очень:

```
let blog_id: Option<u32> = page.find(And(Name("div"),Class("vote-item"))).first()
    .and_then(|x| x.find(Name("span")).first())
    .and_then(|x| x.attr("id").and_then(|x| Some(x.to_string())))
    .and_then(|x| x.split('_').collect::<Vec<_>>().last().and_then(|x| Some(x.to_string())))
    .and_then(|x| x.parse::<u32>().ok());

match blog_id {
    Some(i) => println!("Blog id: {}", i),
    None => println!("Cannot parse blog_id"),
};
```

Возможно ли оформить это как-нибудь более красиво? Если я пытаюсь это как-нибудь упрощать (особенно противный to_string), компилятор незамедлительно начинает ругаться на времена жизни, заимствования и прочую дребедень. Использование `match` или `if let`, подозреваю, приведёт к зашкаливающему количеству лесенок, а если их избегать, то красивость всё равно не особо увеличится. Ещё я пытался написать макрос с циклом, эквивалентный постоянным вызовам `and_then`, но получилось так же некрасиво и to_string никуда не делись.

В идеале что-нибудь похоже на такой Python-эквивалент:

```py
try:
    blog_id = int(page.find("div", {"class": "vote-item"}).\
        find("span")[0].\
        get("id").\
        rsplit("_")[-1])
except Exception:
    blog_id = None
```

<sub>(наверно, лучше просто взять xpath, но вопрос пока не про это :)</sub>

Comment: Есть вот такая штука https://github.com/TeXitoi/rust-mdo. 

Еще в ночном расте можно использовать оператор `?` вместо `try!`.

Answer (score 4):

Если в результате (в возвращаемом значении функции) нужно получить `Result`, для улучшения читабельности кода можно воспользоваться макросом `try!`. Любое значение `Option`, полученное из операций библиотеки `select`, можно преобразовать в `Result` методом `ok_or`, с типом ошибки на ваш выбор, но таким, чтобы он преобразовывался (трейтами `Into`/`From`) в тип ошибки для `Result`, возвращаемого функцией, которая содержит ваш код с использованием `try!`.

```
fn get_blog_id(page: &Document) -> Result<u32, MyDocError> {
    let item = try!(page.find(And(Name("div"),Class("vote-item"))).first()
                    .ok_or(MyDocError::NoVoteItem)));
    let id = try!(item.attr("id")
                  .ok_or(MyDocError::NoIdAttr)));
    ...
}
```

Мне непонятно, в чем проблема со временем жизни заимствований в цепочке `and_then`, но изложенный выше подход позволит этого избежать, поскольку промежуточные значения привязаны к слотам на время вызова содержащей функции и из них можно заимствовать отрезки строк (AKA slices).

Возможный недостаток такого подхода в том, что значения-ошибки в параметрах вызовов `ok_or` создаются в любом случае, так что если тип ошибки имеет нетривиальную инициализацию и/или деструктор (например, создает `String`), это создает ненужную работу даже в случае успешного выполнения. Чтобы этого избежать, можно воспользоваться `ok_or_else` и спрятать инициализацию ошибки в лямбда-выражение, но это несколько ухудшит эстетическое качество кода.

**Добавлено:** Библиотеки макросов [try_or](https://crates.io/crates/try_or) и [try_opt](https://crates.io/crates/try_opt) позволяют написать код раннего возврата `Option` или `Result`, подобный приведенному выше, более компактно. В последних версиях языка использование стандартного макроса `try!` можно заменить на оператор `?`.

Answer (score 2):

Начиная с Rust версии 1.22, оператором `?` можно пользоваться и для быстрого возврата `Option::None`:

```
fn get_blog_id(page: &Document) -> Option<u32> {
    let item = page.find(And(Name("div"), Class("vote-item"))).first()?;
    let id = item.attr("id")?;
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Сейчас как-то сошлись на использовании макроса [hado](https://github.com/ludat/hado-rs), который похож на упомянутый в комментариях mdo, но, по мнению некоторых, немножко лучше:

```
hado! {
    el <- page.find(And(Name("div"),Class("vote-item"))).find(Name("span")).first();
    id_s <- el.attr("id");
    num_s <- id_s.split('_').last();
    num_s.parse::<u32>().ok()
}
```

По сути он делает то же самое, что и мой код с `and_then`: для `Some` вычисляет следующее выражение, а `None` оставляет как есть, и в результате отдаёт `Option` — но с более красивым синтаксисом. (Проблем с временем жизни почему-то не возникло.) (Подобно mdo, юзает многочисленные вложенные друг в друга `Monad::bind`, но пока каких-либо плохих последствий этого не замечено.)

Answer (score 0):

Хм, unwrap говорите не нравится. Давайте посмотрим что мы имеем.

`try!`: Я давно запреметил один макрос, называется `try!`, суть его крайне проста. Если есть ошибка то верни `Result<..,..>` на `fn`, если ошибки нет верни обьект. Принцип как у `unwrap`.

```
macro_rules! try {
    ($e:expr) => (match $e {
        Ok(val) => val,
        Err(err) => return Err(err),
    });
}
```

Описание: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.try.html

Код взят.

```
fn write_to_file_using_try() -> Result<(), MyError> { 
    //Result требуется обязательно реализовывать, так как вы используете try
    let mut file = try!(File::create("my_best_friends.txt")); 
    //если все ок то верни обьект, если нет, заверши функцию и верни Result
    try!(file.write_all(b"This is a list of my best friends."));
    //если все ок то все ок, если нет, заверши функцию и верни Result
    println!("I wrote to the file");
    Ok(())
}
```

Также есть оператор `?` не сталкивалось с ним работать. *`Prefer using ? syntax to try!. ? is built in to the language and is more succinct than try!. It is the standard method for error propagation.`*

`unwrap` Думаю вы с ним уже познакомились, его код описывается зачастую так

```
fn unwrap(self) -> T {
        match self {
            Option::Some(val) => val, //если обьект относится к enum Option::Some(e) значит он не null  и достань значение из него и верни мне
            Option::None => //если обьект относится к enum Option::None значит он относится к нулу и значения никакого мы не получили
              panic!("я упал"),
        }
    }
```

Есть еще множество способов описания, но они у меня не работают(бо неизведано кто их реализовывает) http://m4rw3r.github.io/rust-questionmark-operator

Через `IF` (работает через что захочется, Option, Result, ...)

*`Перепишу код примера на IF`*

```
fn write_to_file_using_try() -> bool { 
    if let Ok(mut file) = File::create("my_best_friends.txt") {
     if let Ok(_e) = file.write_all(b"This is a list of my best friends."){
      println!("I wrote to the file");
      return true;
     }
    }
  false
}
```

Еще пример на `IF` из моего кода

```
pub fn save(&self) -> bool {
        {
            let lock = self.save_file.lock().unwrap();

            if let Some(ref file_s) = *lock {
                if let Ok(file_f) = File::create(file_s){
                    let mut file = BufWriter::new(file_f);

                    let end_w = [10u8; 1];

                    let locker = self.arr.lock().unwrap();
                    for i in locker.iter(){
                        file.write(i.as_bytes()).unwrap();
                        file.write(&end_w);
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        self.warning("no save file...");
        false
    }
```

Comment: `try!` и `?` при ошибке прервут работу функции, а это не надо в моём случае

Comment: Можно воспользоватся более длинным способом, если не надо рвать.  но это буде длинее, хотя и понятно написано.   if let Ok(result) = что-то { }